# Does ITextRenderer supporting base64 images while genarating pdf?

Tags: itext

```
public static void generatePdf(OutputStream os)
        throws IOException, DocumentException,
        com.lowagie.text.DocumentException {

    ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
    String buffer="<html><img src='data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO 9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=='  /></html>";
    renderer.setDocumentFromString(getEscapedString(buffer));
    renderer.layout();
    renderer.createPDF(os, true);
    renderer.finishPDF();
    os.flush();
    os.close();
    log.info("---------------------End generatePdf method---------------------");
}
```

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes, I have tried

Comment: So... Did it work?

Comment: No, It's not giving output. Is there any way to display base64 image in pdf?

Comment: That question is very different from what you originally asked. As far as I can tell (I could be wrong), itext does not natively support data uris. However, since itext does allow images, you **can** use some other means to convert that data uri into a format itext does understand and use that.